# Why is God knowingly and intentionally allowing the majority of people to go to hell without intervening?

Tags: free-will, atheism

God knows the past, present, and future, so why is He allowing the majority of people go to hell? It disgusts me. He knew all this was going to happen, yet did nothing about it. He could have stopped procreation before people became too corrupted.

He could have sent Jesus long before He did and allowed Jesus (or someone) to stay to guide us so that we don't end up in hell, (or He could've sent Jesus **several times** to this world so we didn't lose our way and so we understood what exactly God is wanting from us (yes we have the bible but the bible is just a book and it doesn't show a loving God either) etc.

I mean there are tons of things God could've done to prevent the **majority** of people going to Hell for eternity, or He could've prevented anyone from going to hell.

He could have prevented very traumatic evils from happening to me and trillions of others that made them lose faith and be well on their way to hell.. But He hasn't and didn't and now more people are going to hell than Heaven and He doesn't care because if He did, He would've done something to prevent it.

If God TRULY CARED NOT A SINGLE PERSON WOULD BE GOING TO HELL - I mean except for people who intentionally reject Him and hate Him/love evil.

Know I would do ABSOLUTELY ANYTHING AND EVERYTHING to keep MY children from going to hell, unlike God. He just sent Jesus and really didn't care who got saved and who didn't- He basically just hoped for the best.

On top of that- He **permits** Satan to tempt us, utterly torment, torture, and tempt us then we're blamed and damned to hell.

I don't know, but I can't love a God like that. It makes me sick to my stomach. Even I care more about people going to hell than God does- and YES, I DO! TRUST ME.

Comment: This wall of text needs to be greatly reduced to a few lines and a simple focused question.  And needs to be scoped yo a particular denomination.  Not all Christian groups believe in predestination.

Comment: Not all Christians believe that the **majority** of individuals will be going to hell!

Comment: Even I care more about people going to hell than God does- and YES, I DO! TRUST ME. This comment indicates that you don't understand who and what God is. Which is understandable as there are many 'versions' of God in man's teaching - only God can show who He is - all will get that opportunity to know - and then to realise how wrong they were.

Comment: Prior to creation God foreknew every single human choice, foreknew all the wickedness, foreknew all your pain.  With that foreknowledge He determined to sacrifice His only begotten Son to reconcile the world to Himself and then He created.  I'll repeat that:  God knew the creation of mankind would require the death of His Son and He created us anyway.  There are two things God could have done to prevent anyone from going to hell:  He could have never created us or He could have created us without the ability to choose.  Jesus thought hanging on a cross so we could live and choose was better.

Answer (score 2):

Your question comes from a place of not understanding why God created in the first place.

He didn't want a person - Adam, Eve etc, to be perfect and live with others in perfect harmony by making them that way.

He wanted people who would *choose* good over bad, His way of love etc, over the way of the devil - which is lies, deceit, hate etc.

God allowed evil to intersect the very start of creation with the 'two trees' and the 'liar' in the garden to begin with - that was part of the plan. Man needed to experience the horrors of sin and know that way was not the way they wanted to pursue.

God has taken responsibility for the sin that took place and His plan to deal with the mess included Jesus giving his life at the time He chose. This was planned from the beginning.

God created 'perfect' before man - He made the glorious angels and archangels - these are spirit, and some chose evil in Satan and rebelled against God. He doesn't want that to happen again so He offers man a choice to choose good or not. If we choose good, we are choosing Christ as he is the only way to the Father - having paid for all sin for all people and even defeated death.

Those that chose good will gain eternal life, those that don't will die forever - never seeing life again.

Everyone will be offered the choice when they are free of the deception that reigns over this world. That is why God had prepared at least 2 resurrections and the dead from Adam after will be offered their choice. Hell, whatever it is (the bible is not explicit) is not a place of eternal suffering, but a cessation of life for their own good.

**Why is God knowingly and intentionally allowing the majority of people to go to hell without intervening?**

He isn't.

His plan is proceeding perfectly - this time of great suffering will be nothing compared to what He has prepared for eternity with Him.

> “No eye has seen, no ear has heard, and no mind has imagined what God has prepared for those who love him.” 1 Cor 2:9

> John 3:16 For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

God will intervene and return Jesus to begin the final age - He has prepared a perfect opportunity for all men to choose good, and life eternal.

Comment: You say:  _"prepared at least 2 resurrections and the dead from Adam after will be offered their choice. Hell, whatever it is (the bible is not explicit) is not a place of eternal suffering, but a cessation of life for their own good."_  Neither of these two beliefs are the officially held views of many/most Trinitarian denominations.  Please at least indicate in your answer which denomination/organisation you are seeking to represent in these beliefs.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewShanks, Revelation 20:5 talks of the *first* resurrection occurring when Christ returns, and a second resurrection not until a thousand years later: "*But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished. This is the first resurrection.*". Any denomination that doesn't believe in at least two general resurrections is one that doesn't accept the Bible as their authoritative source.

Comment: @RayButterworth - I believe in the Millenium, just not the above interpretation of it (- nor your interpretation -) esp not "the dead after will be offered their choice" - if that means a second chance to repent I can't see how that comes from Scripture.  (The Bible says enough on Hell, eg Mark 9:42-59.) But what I'm REALLY asking is user47952 is to say in his answer which denomination he is representing; that is what this site requires isn't it? Esp when giving doctrinal answers in which Christians differ.  By the way, not all here accept the Bible as their authoritative source.

Comment: @AndrewShanks, it's not a second chance. There's a third resurrection at the very end where those that rejected their first chance will be destroyed. The second resurrection is for everyone that didn't have their first chance. (The traditional alternative is for "all the people in Africa and Asia that never even heard the name Jesus" to be tortured for all eternity. Why would anyone want to be saved by a god that would do such a thing.)

Comment: @RayButterworth - I believe only 1 resurrection for the good and the evil because of the following - "an _hour_ is coming" John 5:28,29; the righteous will be raised "on the last day" John 6:39,40,44,54 & John 11:24 ie not 1000 years _before_ the last day but "_on_ the last day" (written _five_ times!).  Because the Book of Revelation recounts a vision it should be interpretted in the light of clear teaching such as this. So in Rev 20 we have in order of time (1) casting out of Satan, 2 Millennium, 3 Satan's little season, 4 Last Battle, 5 Resurrection of all, 6 Day of Judgement.  The casting

Comment: @RayButterworth - The casting out of Satan happened in our Lord's earthly ministry (Luke 10:18 & John 12:31), it begins the Gospel Age; in the Millennium, "I saw the _souls_ of those" Rev 20:4, so the first resurrection is of _soul only_ and of the righteous only, ruling in heaven with Christ.. this is happening now in the Gospel Age, the Millennium is the Gospel Age. Now I'm sure you don't agree (eg "resurrection" does not usually mean soul only) I only hope you can see the amillennial interpretation is not entirely baseless or say that we don't accept the Bible as our authoritative source.

Comment: @Andrew you are reading what you are taught to read not what it says. "I saw the souls of those..." You cannot *see a soul*, so based on that fact, "resurrection is of soul only" is nonsense. re the 1000 yrs, 'Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection! The second death has no power... but they will be priests of God and of Christ, and will reign with Him for a thousand years'. Rev 20:6 They cannot reign if they are dead. No they are raised at Christ's return (the last day) and the rest have their opportunity also after 1000 yrs. so says the text, not necessarily tradition.

Comment: They were _souls_.  You can see souls if God chooses you to see them just as you can see things invisible if God enables (2 Kings 6:17).  Besides, Revelation is a vision, Rev 1:10, and stranger things happen in visions.  Nothing to do with tradition, its about rightly dividing the word of God.

Comment: ok, and the souls were beheaded! Right. I'm glad we cleared up the 1000 yrs bit anyway. When we read little bits and claim it's divided rightly, it always lets you down.

Comment: @AndrewShanks You wrote, *By the way, not all here accept the Bible as their authoritative source*. Could you please explain what *you* meant by this?

Comment: @steveowen - Sorry Steve, I wrote that 10 months ago and I cannot remember why I wrote it. You and I clearly accept the Bible as our authoritative source, we just differ on interpretation.  I would still appreciate if you included in your answer which denominational perspective you are writing from.

Comment: @Andrew the answer is from a denomination formerly called Worldwide Church of God which is no longer known by that name. I find no fault with their accurate rendering of the Bible in this matter and consider more *traditional* views to be without merit - Biblically speaking.

Comment: @steveowen - OK thanks for that.  Previously Herbert-Armstrongism, but it has undergone a very welcome doctrinal transformation. . evangelical-times.org/concerning-cults-30/

Comment: @steveowen - I'm talking about "Grace Communion International", the new name for Worldwide Church of God, which is now trinitarian.  But you are part of another splinter group which is not trinitarian.  Not sure why you don't just tell me the name.

Comment: Humanly devised names and labels are unimportant and divisive. There is only one God and He has called one people to Himself thru His one spirit and His one son. Those who consider a denomination as God's preferred group over the others are deluding themselves. There is however an extremely high potential to be part of those who have been distracted from the Biblical truth and perhaps remain lost in this age. But mercifully, not lost in the next. Thankfully God gets to decide who are His, not us, but He has given some guidelines to help us work it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm really glad you feel so strongly about it..but you are wrong to blame God.  God cares far more than any of us ever will.

And God *has* done something decisive about. In the process he has both upheld his own justice, and determination to punish all evil, and not destroyed man's humanity/freedom/turned man into a robot: he gave his one and only Son to die for sinners, taking their punishment upon himself.

First, I do believe in eternal hell and grieve there will be many there.  This is the long-held official view of most Trinitarian denominations (and it is my view too).

You say: "I mean except for people who intentionally reject Him and hate Him/love evil." - That is right.  And who do you think does not fall inti this category?  Little toddlers and younger, and the mentally disabled, OK I grant you they do not fall into this category... but who else?

According to the Bible most of the world fits this category. The world "holds (down) [i.e. suppresses] the truth in unrighteousness" (Romans 1:18 and down to end of chapter).

It is plain there is a God, else there could be no universe.  Even more plainly, the universe that is, with all its order and beauty, is obviously the work of a skilled craftsman.  And then the existence of life, any life, proves beyond doubt there is a God. Yet he is not thanked nor worshipped because the human race is too self-willed, proud, arrogant, too much in love with sin, to be willing even to seek for him.  Instead of seeking for the true God and worshipping him mankind invents gods which suit their sinful appetites (Romans 1:23-25).

Consider what the Bible says in the following passages:-

> Say to them, As I live, declares the Lord God, **I have no pleasure in the death of the wicked**, but that the wicked turn from his way and live; turn back, turn back from your evil ways, for why will you die, O house of Israel?  (Ezekiel 33:11)

> First of all, then, I urge that supplications, prayers, intercessions, and thanksgivings be made for all people, 2 for kings and all who are in high positions, that we may lead a peaceful and quiet life, godly and dignified in every way. 3 This is good, and it is pleasing in the sight of God our Savior, 4 **who desires all people to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth**. 5 For there is one God, and there is one mediator between God and men, the man[a] Christ Jesus, 6 who gave himself as a ransom for all, which is the testimony given at the proper time. 7 For this I was appointed a preacher and an apostle (I am telling the truth, I am not lying), a teacher of the Gentiles in faith and truth. (1 Timothy 2:1-7)

> I am speaking the truth in Christ — I am not lying; my conscience bears me witness in the Holy Spirit — 2 that I have great sorrow and unceasing anguish in my heart. 3 **For I could wish that I myself were accursed and cut off from Christ for the sake of my brothers**, my kinsmen according to the flesh (Romans 9:1-3).

Here the Apostle writes, saying he truly would be willing to spend eternity in hell if this could save the Jews. He is filled with the Holy Spirit. It is thus the heart of God speaking through Paul.  Notice this passage is at the beginning of Romans chapter 9.

> “O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the one who kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to her! **How often I wanted to gather your children together, as a hen gathers her chicks under her wings, but you were not willing!**  (Matthew 23:37).

God says "I would have gathered you, and would have had mercy on you, but you wouldn't let me!"  So, it cannot be God's fault.

What you are asking is that God had made us as robots, always doing the right thing without any choice.  You are wishing he had not made us human.

In love, God made Adam & Eve without sin;
in love, God made them to live forever;
in love, he gave a wonderful garden, forbidding only one thing;
in love, he warned them plainly what would happen if they ate the one forbidden fruit;

yet they rebelled...

So, in love, he made a way of restoration which would not undermine his justice.. he gave his one and only Son to die in the place of sinners, taking their punishment upon himself so they would not be punished who believe on him;

and in love he made the condition of being saved so very easy, faith in his Son and in his substitutionary death;

but in love, he had to make a place for those eternal creatures who would not have him to be their God, so they would not spoil heaven for those who do believe on his Son and love him.

What really is the alternative?  That God steam-roller over his holy justice and let rebels into heaven?  In the eyes of some, he has steam-rollered over his justice enough already by sending his own dear Son, the second person of the triune God, to become a man and take upon himself the punishment due to sinners.. all they need do is humbly repent (turn back to God) and believe on the Lord Jesus Christ.

Will *"most"* go to hell?  That would probably depend on whether you believe that all infants and all who die before they are even born (out of *every* nation) will go to heaven, because the Lord Jesus died for them.  I believe this.  Some evangelicals are more hesitant than me; but some eminent evangelicals firmly believe it too:  https://www.spurgeon.org/resource-library/sermons/infant-salvation/#flipbook/

You said:  *He just sent Jesus and really didn't care who got saved and who didn't - He basically just hoped for the best.*

That is essentially Arminian teaching.  As a Calvinist I don't agree with my Arminian brothers: I don't think that is the teaching of the New Testament. I believe that, in love, God made sure that a certain number of people, his elect, would definitely believe and be saved:

> 3 Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places, 4 even as **he chose us in him before the foundation of the world**, that we should be holy and blameless before him. **In love 5 he predestined us for adoption to himself as sons through Jesus Christ, according to the purpose of his will**, 6 to the praise of his glorious grace, with which he has blessed us in the Beloved.  (Ephesians 1:3-6)

11 In him we have obtained an inheritance, having been predestined according to the purpose of him who works all things according to the counsel of his will, (Ephesians 1:11)

26 But ye believe not, because ye are not of my sheep, as I said unto you. 27 My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me:
28 And I give unto them eternal life; and they shall never perish, neither shall any man pluck them out of my hand. (John 10:26-28)

He does not say you are not of my sheep because you do not believe, but the exact opposite! ... you do not believe because you are not of my sheep.

48 And when the Gentiles heard this, they were glad, and glorified the word of the Lord: and as many as were ordained to eternal life believed.  (Acts 13:48)

26 For consider your calling, brothers: not many of you were wise according to worldly standards, not many were powerful, not many were of noble birth. 27 But **God chose** what is foolish in the world to shame the wise; **God chose** what is weak in the world to shame the strong; 28 **God chose** what is low and despised in the world, even things that are not, to bring to nothing things that are, 29 so that no human being might boast in the presence of God. 30 And **because of him you are in Christ Jesus**, who became to us wisdom from God, righteousness and sanctification and redemption, 31 so that, as it is written, “Let the one who boasts, boast in the Lord.”  (1 Corinthians 1:26-31)

For the children being not yet born, neither having any good or evil, that the purpose of God according to election might stand, not of works, but of him that calls, it was said to her, "The elder shall serve the younger". As it is written "Jacob have loved, but Esau have I hated". (Romans 9:11-13)

Therefore he has mercy on whom he will have mercy and whom he will he hardens.  (Romans 9:18)

All of God's chosen elect people will be saved. He shall save *his people* from their sins. And so *all* Israel shall be saved. (Romans 11:26 - meaning either all the elect or possibly all elect in Israel-biologically)  The false prophets will not be able to fully deceive the elect (Matthew 24:24);  Christ's sheep hear his voice and they will follow him and he will give them eternal life and no one will be able to snatch them out of his hand (John 10:26-28).  *All* that the Father gives me shall come to me (John 6:37). Whom he did predestinate, them he called, whom he called, them he also justified, and whom he justified them he also glorified. (Romans 8:30)

Comment: As a Calvinist don't you also believe that, since man does not possess the ability to respond to God and that ability is divinely granted,  the vast majority are prevented from believing by having the ability withheld?  That the "many" on the wide path to destruction are actually created for that purpose?

Comment: @MikeBorden - "the vast majority" - As C.H. Spurgeon says I don't believe the Devil will defeat our all-conquering, victorious, King of Kings in dragging _the vast majority_ or even _more_ souls into Hell than are saved by His grace.  Surely the power of His infinite grace will do better than that.  Surely the souls who have died by miscarriage, and died in infancy, and by deliberate abortion, will all spend eternity in the Glory, and outweigh the wicked. "Suffer the little children..." (Matt 19:14).

Comment: @MikeBorden - as for your main point, faith in Christ is reasonable, God and we all have a right to expect all to believe, failure to believe is highly blame-worthy.  We must never blame God for any "evil heart of unbelief" (Hebrews 3:12).  The inability to believe springs from a love of wickedness (John 3:19-21).  If God gets the blame for unbelief then why not for _all_ man's wickedness?  A man rapes and then murders a woman: God's fault!  No need to punish him, just blame God.  But such a way is not reasonable.  We are responsible for all our evil, God should get all praise for his mercy.

Comment: The way is narrow and few find it.  It's hard to flip the meaning of this around.  Your second response doesn't sound like any Calvinism I've ever heard or read.  Perhaps I misunderstand reprobation?

Comment: @MikeBorden - "The way is narrow and few find it" is not referring to (and does not include the number of) those who die in infancy (or earlier) since they neither have to find the way, nor walk in it. "All who die in infancy are saved" (Charles Hodge, Systematic Theology, vol 1, p26); "[they] are predestinated to salvation from the foundation of the world" (B.B. Warfield, Two Studies in the History of Doctrine, p230); "Most Calvinistic theologians have held that those who die in infancy are saved" (L. Boetther, The Reformed Doctrine of Predestination, pp 143,144); all quoted in "The Bible

Comment: @MikeBorden - "The Bible on the life Hereafter" by W. Hendriksen, p102.  "The way is narrow.." etc is addressed to those able to understand it; & of that number ie of those able to understand it, "few find it".  It is true that God does get glory out of the punishment of the wicked in Hell, it magnifies his Holy Justice, but, still, the blame belongs ALL to men.  What the LORD says in Ezek 33:11 & what our Lord says in Matthew 23:37 are heart felt and sincere, & no true Calvinist would be so wicked as to believe otherwise.  It would be good to know where you have heard & read about Calvinism

Comment: Maybe 108 billion people have ever been born.  Few could be a pretty big number....1/3 would be 36 billion.(a lot of them babies).

Comment: @MikeBorden - 1st, thanks for comment on John the Baptist answer.  See https://ourworldindata.org/child-mortality-in-the-past especially section "Are these high historical mortality rates plausible, whole of para 3, "The fertility rate was commonly..." etc.  When u compare this slow rate of pop. growth with the huge pop. growth of Israelites in Egypt (under 80 people to between 2 to 2.5 million between 1876 to 1446 bc) it sounds suspicious. Infanticide maybe?  Maybe lots & lots of death by war & lawlessness? (in which cases don't know how many died in infancy). + Include all miscarriages

Comment: @MikeBorden - https://www.worldometers.info/abortions/ - the figure for this year is nuch lower than the number usually given for previous years, often around 50 million for a whole year.... found it !! :- http://www.numberofabortions.com/

Comment: That is a gut wrenching website.

Answer (score 0):

> If God TRULY CARED NOT A SINGLE PERSON WOULD BE GOING TO HELL

No one is forced to obey God. He gave us commandments and the freedom to observe or reject them.

[Matthew 25: 31-40](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025%3A31%E2%80%9340&version=WEB) describes the Final Judgement. The saved are those who clothed the poor, nurtured the sick, etc.

Many will think they're saved and will find out they aren't. Many will think they aren't saved and will find out they are. God alone knows who, how many and whether or not it's the "majority". Individuals should do their best to lead the lives they know they should.

Comment: Hi JarWarren Please state in your answer which Christian viewpoint, which denominational view, you are seeking to represent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is God knowingly and intentionally allowing the majority of people to go to hell without intervening?**

The answer to this question will depend on what individual Christians believe: **Some Christians will say that the vast majority of souls will go to hell when they die, but not all!** Thus this is somewhat subjected to personal belief and interpretations of Scripture.

For example [St. Pio of Pietrelcina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_Pio#/issues/0), a canonized saint and stigmatic of the Catholic Church believed that not a great number of souls go to hell.

I am sure there are others who hold this belief.

> "I believe that not a great number of souls go to hell. God loves us so much. He formed us at his image. God loves us beyond understanding. And it is my belief that when we have passed from the consciousness of the world, when we appear to be dead, God, before He judges us, will give us a chance to see and understand what sin really is. And if we understand it properly, how could we fail to repent?" - [Close encounters of a special kind with Padre Pio:
> The Souls in Purgatory, The Guardian Angel, the devil.](https://caccioppoli.com/Close%20encounters%20of%20Padre%20Pio%20with%20deceased%20souls%20in%20Purgatory,%20Guardian%20Angel,%20devil.%20His%20own%20words%20on%20temptation,%20virtues,%20life..html)

Souls that are in hell, are there through their own desire. They prefer evil over God. God will pardon our sins and restore us to grace, but we must desire this and accept his pardon! Some souls will always refuse this, even on their death beds!

Comment: There are many on the wide path and few on the narrow way.